# Append to second column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv-simple

There is a csv file

```
ip,time,name
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 10:01:03,postgres
2.1.1.1,2018-08-31 12:51:13,oracle
3.1.1.1,2018-08-31 14:32:53,sql
```

I need output as below

```
ip,time,name
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 10:01:03.1,postgres
2.1.1.1,2018-08-31 12:51:13.1,oracle
3.1.1.1,2018-08-31 14:32:53.1,sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed '2,$s/,/.1,/2' file
ip,time,name
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 10:01:03.1,postgres
2.1.1.1,2018-08-31 12:51:13.1,oracle
3.1.1.1,2018-08-31 14:32:53.1,sql
```

This applies a substitution to line 2 and onwards (`2,$`).  The substitution `s/,/.1,/2` replaces the second comma with `.1,`.  It's the `/2` at the end of the substitution command that makes it skip to the second match.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR>1{$2=$2".1"}1' file
```

- `-F,` sets the input field separator
- `BEGIN{OFS=","}` sets the output field separator
- `NR>1{$2=$2".1"}` appends a `.1` if the line number is greater than 0 to the second field